# App for Syncing between Ubuntu and a very restricted Win7?

Tags: applet, notes

I have a school issued laptop running Windows 7 on which I cannot install anything or run .exe.

Apart from just using a USB, any recommendations for syncing text files or am I dreaming?

Answer (score 1):

**First**: Do you have any sort of compiler on it? There is one, called Windows Power Shell, that comes integrated with Windows, some editions at least. You may learn it and create a script. 
**Second**: you may use Windows Shared folder and Samba on Linux. After connection, you may use rsync on Linux to pull the data over network to your Linux machine. 
**Third**: Boot that laptop from LiveUSB and do what you want.

Comment: +1 for the LiveUSB. Even thought most schools would frown upon that, it appears to be the best (In my opinion) option here.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to services like Ubuntu One or Dropbox, you don't have to install anything if you cannot and your files are always accessible from the http interface.